# AGSXMPP disconnects with Google Cloud Connection (GCM)

Tags: xmpp, google-cloud-messaging, agsxmpp

Connecting via XMPP to Google Cloud Connection Server (http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html) for the purpose of sending/receiving notifications to Android devices.

Using AGSXMPP (latest version at time of writing) in a .NET4.5 Console Application to test in.

However, immediately after sending the opening XML - the connection is closed. And I cannot find any explanation.

What is sent:

```
<stream:stream to='gcm.googleapis.com' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>
```

Note that in the Google documenation, the stream is self-closed `<stream />` where as AGSXMPP hasn't sent this - not sure if it makes a difference.

Using wireshark, I can see the message is sent in a stream, to which Google responds with  a TCP Reset - the connection is then closed.

```
xmpp = new XmppClientConnection
         {
            UseSSL = true,
            UseStartTLS = true,
            Server = "gcm.googleapis.com",
            ConnectServer = "gcm.googleapis.com",
            Port = 5235,
            Username = "<SENDER ID>@gcm.googleapis.com",
            Password = <KEY>,
            AutoResolveConnectServer = false,
            SocketConnectionType = SocketConnectionType.Direct,
            KeepAlive = true,
         };

xmpp.Open();
```

I'm assuming that even if the other settings are incorrect (such as login) I should at least be able to get past this stream message and establish a connection of sorts.

Comment: Did you achieve to login ?

Comment: @BarbarosAlp yes, after setting UseSSL to true, and UseStartTLS to false - I was able to login.

Comment: And i figured out something just now that you can set username without "@gcm.googleapis.com" suffix. Now OnAuthError fired and says project not whitelisted. So i filled the form and sent it to google. You filled that form already, right ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some confusion over this scentence in the Google Documentation:

> CCS requires a Transport Layer Security (TLS) connection. That means
>   the XMPP client must initiate a TLS connection.

In relation to agsXMPP, this means `UseSSL` and not `UseStartTLS`. I had both set to true, but `UseStartTLS` sets `UseSSL` to false. Google closes the connection on a non-SSL connection. Setting UseStartTLS to false (even though the docs talking about initating with  a TLS connection) - will allow a SSL connection to establish, and the connection can setup normally.

Working code:

```
xmpp = new XmppClientConnection
         {
            UseSSL = true,
            UseStartTLS = false,
            Server = "gcm.googleapis.com",
            ConnectServer = "gcm.googleapis.com",
            Port = 5235,
            Username = "<SENDER ID>@gcm.googleapis.com",
            Password = <KEY>,
            AutoResolveConnectServer = false,
            SocketConnectionType = SocketConnectionType.Direct,
            KeepAlive = true,
         };

xmpp.Open();
```